# not able to get the access token for discord user next-auth

Tags: next.js, next-auth

hey folks this is my code in `[...nextauth].js`

```
import NextAuth from 'next-auth/next';
import DiscordProvider from 'next-auth/providers/discord';

export default NextAuth({
    
    providers: [
        DiscordProvider({
            clientId: process.env.DISCORD_CLIENT_ID,
            clientSecret: process.env.DISCORD_CLIENT_SECRET,
            callbackUrl : process.env.NEXTAUTH_URL,
            authorization: {
                params: {
                    scope: 'identify email guilds applications.commands.permissions.update'
                }
            },
            callbacks: {
                async session({ session, token, user }) {
                    session.accessToken = token.access_token
                    console.log(session.accessToken);
                    return session;
                },

                async jwt({ token, account }){
                    if (account) token.accessToken = account.access_token
                    return token;
                }
            },
            secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET
        }),
    ],
})
```

but the access token is not logging the only thing loging in console is [console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ji0eB.png)

and this is the code by which the above thing is logging

```
const { data: session, status } = useSession();
const user = session?.user;
console.log(user);
```

please help me in finding the problem due to which the `access token` is not logging

Answer (score 2, accepted):

callbacks needed to put outside of `providers: []`

```
import NextAuth from 'next-auth/next';
import DiscordProvider from 'next-auth/providers/discord';
import { getSession } from 'next-auth/react';

export default NextAuth({
    
    providers: [
        DiscordProvider({
            clientId: process.env.DISCORD_CLIENT_ID,
            clientSecret: process.env.DISCORD_CLIENT_SECRET,
            callbackUrl : process.env.NEXTAUTH_URL,
            token: "https://discord.com/api/oauth2/token",
            userinfo: "https://discord.com/api/users/@me",
            authorization: {
                params: {
                    scope: 'identify email guilds applications.commands.permissions.update'
                }
            },
        }),
    ],
    callbacks: {
        async session({ session, token, user }) {
            session.accessToken = token.access_token
            return session;
        },

        async jwt({ token, account }){
            if (account){
                token.accessToken = account.access_token
            console.log(token.accessToken);
            }
            return token;
        }
    },
    secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
})
```